# How to format the rows and columns of a CSV in Java

Tags: java, csv

My ultimate goal is to continuously gather data (probably a good 700 lines) and send it off to a CSV for later review. 
Currently, my code is properly sending the data, but it seems to be printing in the same spot - overriding the last output and printing the latest in its place. I can't seem to find how to increment rows/columns with every new output.

My code:

```
String output = ("The difference b/w sent and received is: " + milliseconds + " milliseconds" );
try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("/storage/self/primary/Download/test.xlsx"))) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(sentTimestamp);
    sb.append('\n');
    sb.append(responseTimestamp);
    sb.append('\n');
    sb.append(output);
    sb.append('\n');
    writer.write(sb.toString());
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

And it is displaying as such:

---

`2019-11-21 07:47:59.18`

`2019-11-21 07:47:59.492`

`The difference b/w sent and received is: 312 milliseconds`

---

That's great, but with every new sent and received, I want it to print on a new set of three lines. How do I specify the rows/columns within my CSV?

Comment: If you want to append to the file then open a writer in append mode `new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("c:/...", true));`

Comment: Is that in place of: (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("/storage/self/primary/Download/test.xlsx") ??

Comment: However, I would just leave the writer open, write all the data, then close it, rather than open/close for each set of data; Unless of course the data writing is highly intermittent.

Comment: Yes, it is in place of your current PrintWriter.